# Efficient way to determine highest value (with or without offset)

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, sortedlist

I'm currently using a SortedList in a loop to sort some values in descending order:

```
for(...)
{
    float rawValue;
    float offset;
    sortedList.Add(rawValue + offset, index);
}
```

I'm interested in finding out if `sortedList[0]` (i.e. the entry with the highest rawValue+offset) is also the highest entry if we had sorted the entries by their raw values without the offsets?

The obvious solution is to have another sortedRawValuesList populated in the same loop, but I think there are quicker and more memory efficient ways of achieving that?

Thanks!

Comment: Does offset change in various iterations?

Comment: Yes both rawValue and offset change in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not simply keep track of the highest rawValue as you iterated? If the offsets change through each iteration, you would probably want to save the offset as well.

```
float highestRawVal = float.MinVal;
float offset_ForHighestRawVal = float.MinVal;
for(...)
{
    float rawValue;
    float offset;
    sortedList.Add(rawValue + offset, index);
    if(highestRawVal < rawVal)
    {
        highestRawVal = rawValue;
        offset_ForHighestRawVal = offset;
    }
}

if (highestRawVal + offset_ForHighestRawVal == sortedList[0])
    Console.WriteLine("They Match");
```

Then you could simply check afterwards if they match.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather inefficient to add a bunch of values to a `SortedList` just to sort that data.  You're effectively doing an "insertion sort", which is O(n^2).  Most widely used sorting algorithms are O(n*log(n)).

On top of that, if you just need the max value you can loop over the data just once and compute the max in O(1) time.

To find the Max value simply use LINQ's `Max` function:

```
IEnumerable<X> data = ...;

float max = data.Max(item => doSomeComputation(item));
```

To get the item that generate the max value you can use MaxBy. (Unfortunately .NET doesn't ship it directly, you need to write/add it yourself.)

```
X maxItem = data.MaxBy(item => doSomeComputation(item));

public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source
    , Func<TSource, TKey> selector
    , IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    }
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Source was empty");
        }

        TSource maxItem = iterator.Current;
        TKey maxValue = selector(maxItem);

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TKey nextValue = selector(iterator.Current);
            if (comparer.Compare(nextValue, maxValue) > 0)
            {
                maxValue = nextValue;
                maxItem = iterator.Current;
            }
        }
        return maxItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply utilize LINQ to do this sort for you?

```
var sortedList = // Get List

var withOffsets = sortedList.Select(x => new { Original = x, Offset = x + offset }).OrderBy(x => x.Offset);

if(sortedList.First() == withOffsets.First())
   // True!
```

Comment: Why sort the data in the first place if you just need to find the item with the largest value?

Comment: The OP is asking if the first item sorted by rawValue is also the first item sorted by raw + offset - so in both sitations, he's saying he needs sorted values.

Comment: The first item in a sorted sequence is either the min or the max value (depending on the type of sort).  You can compute the min or max value directly without sorting at all if that's all you need.  It will be substantially more performant, easier to read, more understandable, and just all around better.

Comment: If OP is concerned about the speed and efficiency of merely adding a second list... I doubt adding LINQ queries is going to make him happy... Pretty sure Josh's response nailed it